# Returning both old and new entities from Spring/MongoDB findAndModify

Tags: spring, mongodb, mongodb-query, spring-data, mongodb-java

We're using MongoDB via Spring Data and rely on the `findAndModify` operation to update existing entities or create new ones.

In the `findAndModify` we can configure to return old state of the entity or the new one using `returnNew(...)`.

**Is there some way to return both old and new entities from `findAndModify`?**

We need to compare entity states before and after update, this is why we need both instances.

At the moment we're resorting to `requireNew(false)` and then manually update a copy of the old instance, something like this:

```
public Pair<Data> saveItems(String id, List<Item> items) {
    final Query findById = ...;

    final Update update = new Update();
    // This is what we actually update
    update.set(ENTITY_FIELD_ITEMS, newItems);
    update.inc(ENTITY_FIELD_VERSION, 1);
    // Try updating and return the old data 
    final Data oldData = operations.findAndModify(findById, update,
        FindAndModifyOptions.options().upsert(true).returnNew(false), Data.class);

    // Copy or create new instance
    final Data newData;
    if (oldData == null) {
        newData = new Data(id);
    }
    else {
        newData = new Data(oldData);
    }
    // Apply the same update
    newData.setItems(newItems);
    newData.incVersion();
    return new Pair<Data>(oldData, newData);
}
```

Works but isn't pretty as we have to redo the same things we already do in the `Update` on the copy of the old instance.

What we've also considered was first loading an old instance and the running the update but it's not safe as the entity may have been modified between the load and the update. This may be addressed with versions and optimistic locking, but that makes things even more complicated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is there some way to return both old and new entities from findAndModify?

**No**, there's no way to return both old and new value with [`findAndModify`](http://api.mongodb.com/java/3.2/com/mongodb/DBCollection.html#findAndModify-com.mongodb.DBObject-com.mongodb.DBObject-com.mongodb.DBObject-boolean-com.mongodb.DBObject-boolean-boolean-boolean-long-java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit-).

Comment: Yep, looks like there's no other way.

Answer (score 0):

No, there's no way to return both old and new value with findAndModify.

But if you want to compare entitiy state before and after updating do the below steps

1. Just before updating retrieve the data using primary key and store in oldData variable
2. in your findAndModify query change returnNew to true to save it under newData

Below sample sudocode will return you both values

```
    public Pair<Data> saveItems(String id, List<Item> items) {
    final Query findById = ...;

    final Update update = new Update();
    // This is what we actually update
    update.set(ENTITY_FIELD_ITEMS, newItems);
    update.inc(ENTITY_FIELD_VERSION, 1);
    // Try updating and return the old data 
    final Data oldData = findById(); //query to retrieve existing data
    final Data newData = operations.findAndModify(findById, update,
        FindAndModifyOptions.options().upsert(true).returnNew(true), Data.class);

      return new Pair<Data>(oldData, newData);
    }
```

Comment: There may be another update between the first `find` and the following `findAndModify`, so `oldData` may be obsolete.

Comment: findAndModify is thread-safe so it won't happen and as both steps occurs one after another your use case will be suffices.

Comment: Thread safety has nothing to do with this. There may be several threads processing data in parallel. So even as `findAndModify` is atomic, a sequence of `find` and `findAndModify` is not. Next, the database may be accessed from different processes or even machines. There is no way to guarantee that no update operation will happen between `find` and `findAndUpdate`.

Comment: This is going to create a race condition with multiple writers. At the very least I imagine you would want to do findAndModify followed by find so that you can have the document state that was actually modified consistently. This would allow you to archive it or whatever you wanted to do with it. Then the question is if the client will tolerate inconsistency on the returned state. If it's like a REST API or whatever... things might be OK with an eventually consistent read after a write. For more sensitive applications, you need to devise an external pessimistic locking strategy.