# Is it possible to lock some entries in MongoDB and do a query that do not take into account the locked recors?

Tags: spring, mongodb

I have a mongoDB that contains a list of "task" and two istance of executors. This 2 executors have to read a task from the DB, save it in the state "IN_EXECUTION" and execute the task. Of course I do not want that my 2 executors execute the same task and this is my problem.

I use the transaction query. In this way when An executor try to change state of the task it get "write exception" and have to start again and read a new task. The problem of this approach is that sometimes an Executor get a lot of errors before it can save the change of task state correctly and execute a new task. So it is like I have only one exector.

Note:
- I do not want to block my entire DB on read/write becouse in this way I will slow down the entire process.
- I think it is necessay to save the state of the task because it could be a long task.

I asked if it is possible to lock only certain record and execute a query on the "not-locked" records but each advices that solves my problem will be really appriciated.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT1:
Sorry, I simplified the concept in the question above. Actually I extract n messages that I have to send. I have to send this messages in block of 100 messages so my executors will split the messages extracted in block of 100 and pass them to others executors basically.
Each executor extract the messages and then update them with the new state. I hope this is more clear now.

```
@Transactional(readOnly = false, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
public List<PushMessageDB> assignPendingMessages(int limitQuery, boolean sortByClientPriority,
        LocalDateTime now, String senderId) {
    final List<PushMessageDB> messages = repositoryMessage.findByNotSendendAndSpecificError(limitQuery, sortByClientPriority, now);
    long count = repositoryMessage.updateStateAndSenderId(messages, senderId, MessageState.IN_EXECUTION);
    return messages;
}
```

DB update:

```
public long updateStateAndSenderId(List<String> ids, String senderId, MessageState messageState) {
    Query query = new Query(Criteria.where(INTERNAL_ID).in(ids));
    Update update = new Update().set(MESSAGE_STATE, messageState).set(SENDER_ID, senderId);
    return mongoTemplate.updateMulti(query, update, PushMessageDB.class).getModifiedCount();
}
```

Comment: You cannot just use an atomic update to `$set` the state to "IN_EXECUTION" only when it is not already in "IN_EXECUTION" ?

Comment: Thanks for your ansers but I don't think I solve this problem "...The problem of this approach is that sometimes an Executor get a lot of errors before it can save the change of task state correctly and execute a new task. So it is like I have only one exector." right?

Comment: Why would you get a lot of errors? What errors? The atomic update will not create an error, it will either have updated the document or not (if the other server happened to update it at the same time, but that should be very rare, as the interval between selecting and updating the next task will be only a few ms).

Comment: I get "WriteConflict". When I get this error it means that the other server is executing the task so I have to read others task from the DB and do not execute the one I have just read.

Comment: And this happens a lot? How long does it take for the other server to process the task? You cannot get another task (by retrying your task selection transaction) before that? Is there only one task in the queue?

Comment: Better add an outline of your transaction (with the relevant database updates) to the query.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MongoDB as a queue service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9274777/mongodb-as-a-queue-service)

Comment: Doing this for 100 messages in one transaction is probably the issue. Better do it one by one. And combining the two queries into a single `findAndModify` should also help.

Comment: Do you know how to do a findAndModify in java/spring?  the update method return the number of documents updated (I know I can do that with a separate find and update, I ask you if there is an update that return the documents updated).

Comment: There is a Spring example here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/37275914/14955

Comment: There is a findAndModify for collections?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to do the locking one-by-one.

Trying to lock 100 records at once and at the same time have a second process also lock 100 records (without any coordination between the two) will almost certainly result in an overlapping set unless you have a huge selection of available records.

Depending on your application, having all work done by one thread (and the other being just a "hot standby") may also be acceptable as long as that single worker does not get overloaded.